# Receive async requests python

Tags: python, asynchronous, post

I have several Flask servers which handle POST requests and returns some values. I need to run an infinite process which sends requests to all servers, waiting until first response, update internal state based on that response and send new request to that server again. Here is a pseudocode for this:

```
obj = SomeObject()
requests = [obj.make_request() for _ in range(10)]
responses = grequests.imap(requests, size=10)
for response in responses:
    obj.update_state(response)
    requests.append(obj.make_request())
```

What is the proper implementation of such logic in python?

Comment: We are not going to write the code for you. Or do you have any specific question?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not asking for a code -- I'm asking for the approach. Please help me with what should I change in my code or describe critical drawbacks of my approach and propose a solution for solving them. Thanks in advance!